What would be a "cron" alternative?
I'm reading that using cron for scheduled and repeated tasks could be a safety risk.  Moreover, some other systems are deprecating it...
Now, in the minimized server version of UBUNTU 24.04.1 LTS, it is not included by default.  I could install it while ignoring the safety warning, maybe, but wanted to know what alternatives there are istead?  Let's say, how can I let a bash script run at some exact times every day?

What "safety warning" are you referring to?

This question is similar to: How to execute a script periodically without using crontab?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The solution would be to use SystemD timers and service combinations.
The following is an example SystemD Service and a SystemD Timer:
custom-process.timer (placed in /etc/systemd/system):
[Unit]
Description=My Custom Process Timer
Requires=custom-process.service

[Timer]
Unit=custom-process.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* 01:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target

custom-process.service (placed in /etc/systemd/system):
[Unit]
Description=My Custom Process
Wants=custom-process.timer
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 custom-script.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/custom_script/
User=user
Group=user
NoNewPrivileges=true
UMask=0177
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

The custom process service definition file tells SystemD how to run the script and under what user with what privileges and what working directory to cd into for the runtime.  The timer definition defines on what calendar time/basis (like a cron script does!) to execute the service on.  In the above, this executes my custom script once a day at 1:00 AM.  The custom process is a custom python script that is in /home/user/custom_script (which is what the working directory is set to so the 'relative' path is understood to custom-script.py but also so any other local python files my script references work)
Once you have a proper service and timer object defined, you have to reload the SystemD definitions with sudo systemctl daemon-reload.
To test the service to make sure the definition works, run sudo systemctl start custom-process.service
To test the timer, use sudo systemctl --now enable custom-process.timer.  That will start the automated timer at boot time AND run the timer at the next defined run-time per the definition.

Details on the service file and its various options can be found in SystemD's documentation on service file units.
Details on the Timer file and its options can be found in SystemD's documentation on timer file units.

@user68186 if it's a custom script the timer will execute it automatically.  Especially if it's a one-off.  If the service doesn't fork into a daemon or run as a daemon itself, it's considered a oneoff service, which is triggered by the timer. Because OP is using this in place of cron, we can assume the tasks are 'oneoff' executed one at a time on a schedule, meaning the service can be disabled (not autostarted at boot) but the timer can be enabled (and triggers the service automatically).  Been doing this for a few years with one-offs that used to be cronjobs :P

Thanks @ThomasWard for the excellent explanation.

Checking your answer as more detailed and informative.  Note that the [Install]-WantedBy part is needed either in the .timer or in the .service file but not in both.

@Hristo correct, but it's not against policy to include it in both to make SURE both parts are available

You could use systemd timers. I don't know much about server security, but systemd timers solve basically the same problem as cron, although they work in a completely different way.
See The Arch Wiki for more information.
There are also multiple implementations of cron, such as anacron or cronie. Perhaps one is more secure than the other?

anacron isn't going to work the same as cron does. If cronie doesn't exist either, then OP is going to want to use SystemD timers.

Thanks for answering.  I found that systemd timers are very well explained with examples in the SUSE documentation

Note that this is more or less a link only answer by referring to a third party source and not really a complete answer.  Per Ask Ubuntu policies, this answer may be deleted for that sole reason.

@ThomasWard I don't know what else I could say here. After all, is it's not like Hristo had asked for a tutorial. Hristo only asked if an alternative existed.

@TSJNachos117 the only reason i'm cautioning you is because link only answers like the "Read the Arch wiki on this" can expire and the site policy is to not look fondly on link-only answers.  That's all.
